# Only 1 entry is written to the JSON file, not all

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import json

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.hoyolab.com/circles/2/27/official?page_type=27&page_sort=events')

data={}

block = browser.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "mhy-article-list__body")
all_links = block.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME,"a")
all_title = block.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'h3')

for posts in all_links:
    post = posts.get_attribute('href')

for titles in all_title:


    title = titles.get_attribute('title')

    data = {
        'post':post,
        'title':title
    }

with open('result.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    json.dump(data, file, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)


browser.quit()
```

I have a python script that runs through a directory, searches for a string and prints the file and string when reading the string, however the json file outputs only one occurrence of the string, am I missing something in the json loop?

Comment: Every time through your loop, you throw away whatever is in `data` and replace it with the current values. You need to collect each dict value into a list instead.

Comment: Imagine if instead of a loop, you had a series of explicit `data = {...}; data = {...}; data = {...}; ...` assignments. Do you see the problem?

Comment: There's a similar problem with `for posts in all_links`, where `post` is overwritten without being stored in a separate container. What exactly are you trying to save in the results file? How do you intend to use this data?